# How to add checkboxes in GridView Cells on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2019

So I am new to ASP.NET, and am having trouble finding this on the web too. What I am trying to accomplish is adding checkboxes inside the cells of the table I would like to create. Currently, the code I have implemented presents a whole new check box column, as show below:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="Gv1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Check Box">
                <itemtemplate>
                    <asp:checkbox ID="cb" runat="server"></asp:checkbox>
                </itemtemplate>
            </asp:templatefield>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Again, what I am trying to accomplish is make each of the empty cells on the grid consist of a check box. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't share how many columns you need?

But, lets say we want 20 columns, and 10 rows deep.

So, we have this markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table"
  OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
</asp:GridView>
```

And our code to load is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        //ADD 20 columns
        int i;
        int j;
        for (i = 1;i <= 20;i++)
            rstData.Columns.Add("C" + i,typeof(bool));

        // now add 10 rows
        for (i = 1;i <= 10;i++)
        {
            DataRow OneRow = rstData.NewRow();
            // lets check the first 5 columns
            for (j = 0; j < OneRow.Table.Columns.Count; j++)
                OneRow[j] = (j <= 4);
            
            rstData.Rows.Add(OneRow);
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

We VERY unfortunately have to deal with default check boxes on a grid are read only and not enabled. So, in the on- row data bound even, we have to add this:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            foreach (TableCell c in e.Row.Cells)
            {
                CheckBox ck = c.Controls[0] as CheckBox;
                ck.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

And now we get this:

[image]

## Edit: Example with check box(s) from data table.

So, if you need to setup some check boxes in the gv, then I suggest you actually add the check boxes as columns and use REAL asp.net check box  controls.

So, with this gv markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" class="table" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID"  >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName"   HeaderText="FirstName"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName"    HeaderText="LastName"   />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City"        HeaderText="City"       />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName"   HeaderText="HotelName" HeaderStyle-Width="200"   />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActice" runat="server"
                    Checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Smoking"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSmoking" runat="server"
                    Checked='<%# Eval("Smoking") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Balcony"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBalcony" runat="server" 
                    Checked='<%# Eval("Balcony") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And now our code behind to load above is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }
    void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName ";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rst = new DataTable();
                rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rst;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

And now we see/get this:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I already had the columns set that's why I did not add it, but I tried your code for the RowDataBound, and for some reason I am getting an out of range exception.

Comment: Well, you could create a blank new test web page - the markup and code as posted is what I used for the screen shots - so that code "as posted" does work.  It was not quite clear if you looking to make a grid of check box, or that you wanted to add a column to a existing data table or some data - perhaps for selecting multiple rows? So, do we just need one extra check box column, or do we need a bunch?

Comment: So although I have 9 columns, I want to only have 7 of these columns to consist of check boxes.

Comment: Ok, nice - this is called problem scope, and by limiting the scope of the problem, we can now drive towards a solution. So, since we know AHEAD of time that we need/want/have 7 check box columns? Ok, then next question is/are those columns feed from the database - will they thus be "bound" data (their values come from the query/data that drives the Gv? since we at least now know we only need/want 7 check box columns, then the problem scope is FAR more limited.

Comment: See my edit + 2nd example with 3 columns of check boxes - it should give you some ideas as to how this can/should work.

Comment: Oh I see how this works now. Thanks! I created a blank web page and looked it over and now I have an idea as to how I can use it for my code.

Comment: Well, as noted, as my 2nd example above shows - if you know and want a fixed number of check boxes, you are much better to add each check box to the markup as the 2nd example shows.